# MySQL - SELECT a single value from two optional records based on a query param value

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my simplified scenario.
I have DB records in 'store_config' table:

```
ID  store_id   value
1   0           val1
2   10          val2
3   7           val3
4   99          val4
```

All records are optional - may or may not exist.

store_id column is unique.

I want to run a query:

```
WHERE store_id=?
```

So that:
The query should return a value matching the store_id from the query param if it exists, otherwise return value matching store_id 0 if it exists.

storeId=0 record is considered to be a default value and returned only if there is no existing record for the supplied storeId query param. That's the logic behind it.

Comment: have you tried with limit?
SELECT store_id from table where store_id=paramname LIMIT 1 ?

Comment: `there may be other storeId records in between` ... there is no internal order to a MySQL table.  I have to agree with the above comments; it is not entirely clear what you want to do here.

Comment: @Tim I tried to rewrite the description, is it clear enough now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select t.*
from t
where store_id in (@store_id, 0)
order by store_id desc
limit 1;
```

This assumes (as implied by your question) that there is only one row in the table for each store id.  If that is not the case, you might want a more complicated version:

```
select t.*
from t
where store_id = @store_id
union all
select t.*
from t
where store_id = 0 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.store_id = @store_id);
```

Comment: yes, there is only one record per store_id but thanks for extending your answer.

Comment: I just realised it doesn't solve my problem. So if both records are present and the param is store_id = 10, I want to get the value for that store - not storeId=0

Comment: please see description of the issue again, I clarified it a bit more

Comment: @mwdev This correctly answers your question, as does my answer (more or less).

Comment: @mwdev . . . That is what both these queries do.

Comment: yeah you're right - sorry guys I was confused for a second. It's correct! ;]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach using a `LIMIT` trick:

```
SELECT ID, store_id, `value`
FROM store_config
WHERE store_id IN (0, 10)
ORDER BY store_id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

The trick here is that if `ID=10` is present, then its record would be the one retained.  If `ID=10` is *not* present, but `ID=0` is present, then this record would be retained.  Otherwise, the result set would be empty.

Comment: @mwdev . . . I find it amusing that this is accepted and has upvotes given that it uses the wrong columns for the comparisons.

Comment: @GordonLinoff For what it's worth, I gave this answer on a cell phone, while on a crowded metro train.

Comment: . . The OP accepted an incorrect answer posted after a correct answer.  The OP can do whatever s/he wants.  I'm just amused by it.

Comment: @Gordon you're right, wrong colums is one thing but I just realised it doesn't solve my problem. So if both records are present and the param is store_id = 10, I want to get the value for that store

Comment: @mwdev My answer in fact should cover this situation.  If both `store_id` of 1 and 10 are present, the single latter record would be retained.

Comment: @mwdev . . . The spirit of Tim's original answer is correct (and he has fixed it).  He just put in the wrong columns -- an error that I'm sure I've made many times and is really easy to do on small screens.

Comment: I know, I gave it a vote up, sorry for my confusion guys, still I could pick only one answer as for closing the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT (IFNULL((SELECT  store_id   FROM @tbl Where id = @store_id LIMIT 1),0))
```

Comment: I think I got the idea here but other answers are more elegant and subqueries is what I wanted to avoid. Thanks.